# Eruv in a Midbar?

Tags: maseches-eruvin

How do the halachic requirements for setting up an eruv in a midbar (Wildnerness) [like when camping] differ from those of setting up an eruv in a city?

Comment: It's a machloket rishonim if a midbar is a reshut harabbim. In particular for those who rely on big city eruvin, it could be a contradiction to treat a desert as a karmelis.

Comment: If there’s a gate of some sort that encompasses the encampment, an actual eiruv (the food) is not needed in a camp type setting. See Siman 366:2 MB and Biur Halacha there as well. Not in all instances or according to all opinions